# Fit an image into a CSS grid cell

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to fit an image onto a grid cell but I've had no luck, here's my JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/RomelF/njax3ufw/1/

and here's my html:

```css
.project-tile {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

#p1 {
  background-color: grey;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  margin: 100px;
}

#p1 img {
  object-fit: fill;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <nav id="navbar">
    <h3><a href="#">Click here for contact info</a></h3>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <section id="welcome-section">
    <h1 id="name">My name's Romel, here are some of my projects:</h1>
  </section>
  <section id="projects">
    <div class="project-tile" id="p1"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/tz4vopS.png" alt="Tribute Page"></div>
    <div class="project-tile" id="p2"></div>
    <div class="project-tile" id="p3"></div>
    <div class="project-tile" id="p4"></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the image to occupy the full grid?

Comment: I'd like the image to fill the #p1 grid cell.

Comment: It is already working like that: https://imgur.com/gDI0dtX